# Is using 'new Function' in javascript as an inner function (within closure) considered a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, function

When I read about curry function, I think it's hard to create a recursion for building nested function. Then I take a look at [ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda)'s implementation, it's
true that to create an curried function with arbitrary number of arguments. Then,
why not building it with string like this:

```
function curry(fn, arity) {
  arity = typeof arity === 'undefined' ? fn.length : arity

  if (arity < 1) {
    return fn
  }

  function build(n, space = 2, args = []) {
    if (n < 1) {
      args = args.map(arg => 'a' + arg)
      return `fn(${args.join(', ')})`
    } else {
      return `function (a${n}) {\n${' '.repeat(space)}` +
        `return ${build(n - 1, space + 2, args.concat(n))}\n` +
        `${' '.repeat(space - 2)}}`
    }
  }
  const curryCreator = new Function('fn', 'return ' + build(arity))
  return curryCreator(fn)
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
function sum5(a, b, c, d, e) {
  return a + b + c + d + e
}

const sum = curry(sum5)
```

Which will produce this:

```
function (a5) {
  return function (a4) {
    return function (a3) {
      return function (a2) {
        return function (a1) {
          return fn(a5, a4, a3, a2, a1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How bad it can be to use `new Function` for this functionality?

The use case is just to generate a function and argument placeholder like
in the example above. My question is more specific than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) which
addresses the generic use case of `eval` or `new Function`. As you can see
in my example, it's a private function which is won't be called in another
place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @Nit I updated the question.